# Spring: I wish to create a junit test for a web application - WebApplicationContext needed

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring

I am writing a junit test in order to (surprisingly) test a part of my app as a standalone.

Thing is I execute the following line in a constructor being invoked in the unit test:

```
WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext = ContextLoader.getCurrentWebApplicationContext();
```

How would I go about to set up a web context when running a simple unit test?

Thanks

Comment: I came up with this solution which solved my problem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14830957/965176

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- In unit tests, test with mocks.
- In integration tests you may actually want to start an embedded servlet container. [Here's a approach](http://confluence.highsource.org/display/Hifaces20/Hifaces20+Testing+package+-+testing%2C+tracing+and+debugging+web+applications+with+Jetty).

Answer (score 3):

You usually don't make use of a WebApplicationContext in unit testing. Unit testing is about testing classes in isolation. You shouldn't have to start the whole application to make the test. If you need it, you can mock an HttpServletRequest object with a mocking framework, like [EasyMock](http://easymock.org/).