# How to inject ServletContext for JUnit tests with Spring?

Tags: java, spring, junit, cxf

I want to unit test a RESTful interface written with Apache CXF.

I use a ServletContext to load some resources, so I have:

```
@Context
private ServletContext servletContext;
```

If I deploy this on Glassfish, the ServletContext is injected and it works like expected. But I don't know how to inject the ServletContext in my service class, so that I can test it with a JUnit test.

I use Spring 3.0, JUnit 4, CXF 2.2.3 and Maven.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2665773/spring-i-wish-to-create-a-junit-test-for-a-web-application-webapplicationconte

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In your unit test, you are probably going to want to create an instance of a [MockServletContext](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/mock/web/MockServletContext.html).

You can then pass this instance to your service object through a setter method.

Answer (score 18):

As of Spring 4, @WebAppConfiguration annotation on unit test class should be sufficient, see [Spring reference documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.1.6.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#integration-testing-annotations)

```
@ContextConfiguration
@WebAppConfiguration
public class WebAppTest {
    @Test
    public void testMe() {}
}
```

Comment: This has no effect in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you want to read resources with servletContext.getResourceAsStream or something like that, for this I've used Mockito like this:

```
 @BeforeClass
void setupContext() {

    ctx = mock(ServletContext.class);
    when(ctx.getResourceAsStream(anyString())).thenAnswer(new Answer<InputStream>() {
        String path = MyTestClass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath()
                + "../../src/main/webapp";

        @Override
        public InputStream answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
            Object[] args = invocation.getArguments();
            String relativePath = (String) args[0];
            InputStream is = new FileInputStream(path + relativePath);
            return is;
        }
    });

}
```