# Unit testing Spring MVC web-app: Could not autowire field: private javax.servlet.ServletContext

Tags: unit-testing, spring, spring-mvc

I would like to make tests for my web-app, but context configuration crashes on autowiring `servletContext`. Error below. Autowiring `servletContext` works good when i run web-app on tomcat/jetty.

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext ...
>   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'testController': Injection of autowired
>   dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: private javax.servlet.ServletContext
>   com.test.controllers.TestController.servletContext; nested exception
>   is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   matching bean of type [javax.servlet.ServletContext] found for
>   dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
>   candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("classpath:applicationContext.xml")
public class FirstTest {

    @Test
    public void doTest() throws Exception {
        // ...  
    }
}
```

TestController

```
@Controller
public class TestController {

    @Autowired
    private ServletContext servletContext;

    ... 
}
```

Comment: See this related answer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2674697/how-to-inject-servletcontext-for-junit-tests-with-spring

Comment: Thanks. How to use `MockServletContext` with `@ContextConfiguration` ?

Comment: Just include a <bean/> definition for the `MockServletContext` in your `applicationContext.xml` file

Answer (score 25, accepted):

According to [ptomli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/134894/ptomli) hint, defining `MockServletContext` bean do the trick.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.mock.web.MockServletContext"/>
```

Another problem, which appeared was [tilesConfigurer](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/tiles2/TilesConfigurer.html), that doesn't work:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tilesConfigurer' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Soultion: separate tiles config from applicationContext.xml and don't use tiles in jUnit tests.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            classpath:applicationContext.xml
            classpath:tilesConfig.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
</web-app>
```

Comment: It works. Another option is to anotate the test with @WebAppConfiguration

Answer (score 11):

I have added `@WebAppConfiguration` under the test class and problem disappeared